# wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am running this code https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack_demo but getting this error

[image]

The file is https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack_demo/blob/master/app/views/users/index.erb. Can someone explain me this error ? The only thing I have different from that app code is I am running Ruby 2.2.2 instead of 2.3.1 but I don't think that is the reason of the error.

Comment: Please, post the error message. Not a photo of the error message, the error message. Also, please post the code. Not a link to the code, the code. See [mcve] for hints.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what syntax that is but you could use `<% field_set_tag do %>` or `tag(:fieldset, ..., true)`

As shown in: [tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag) and [field_set_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-field_set_tag) docs.

Comment: Very new to rails and this answer, although not as clear as I'd like, helped me figure it out. I was reading the docs and writing `<%= tag.tr do %>` into my .html.erb, when the docs are referring to straight ruby, and I needed to be writing `<%= tag :tr do %>`.
Not posting a separate answer, because this one _basically_ says that, but perhaps someone will find my explanation clearer.